# Converting a standard setup/loop sketch to a low power application?

Tags: power, sleep

Suppose I have a typical setup/loop style sketch, such as this one which turns on an LED when a button is pressed.

How do I modify this so that it enters low power mode, awakes on the button press, and puts itself back into low power mode when its logic has finished?

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  // desired: enter low power mode here
}
void loop() {
  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  // desired: awake from low power mode here
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  // desired: back to low power mode here
}
```

Comment: For which arduino board?

Comment: @Jot, I'm open to input about any of them.  If some are especially good for low power applications I would be interested in hearing about that.

Comment: Some are. For example a "bare bones" atmega328p. See: https://www.gammon.com.au/power Some Arduino MKR boards can be powered with Lipo battery. The ARM M0+ processor of the MKR boards can go into sleep mode, but I don't know if there is a library for that which supports all modes. I also don't know which MKR boards use very little current for the rest of the components of the board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sketch is almost identical to the **powerDownWakeExternalInterrupt.ino** sketch that comes with the `LowPower` Library. I'm using `INPUT_PULLUP` and a N.O. push button switch to trigger it to wake up and turn an LED on.

```
#include "LowPower.h"
const byte wakeUpPin = 2;

// Just a handler for the pin interrupt.
void wakeUp(){}

void setup(){

  // Configure wake up pin as input.
  // This will consumes few uA of current.
  pinMode(wakeUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

}

void loop(){

  // Allow wake up pin to trigger interrupt on low.
  attachInterrupt(0, wakeUp, LOW);

  // Enter power down state with ADC and BOD module disabled.
  // Wake up when wake up pin is low.
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);

  // Disable external pin interrupt on wake up pin.
  detachInterrupt(0); 

  // Do something here.
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

}
```