# Are any Arduino boards especially suited for low-power operation?

Tags: power, battery

The Arduino project has done an excellent job in providing a portable software interface to a number of different hardware systems.

Are there any Arduino-compatible systems which are especially applicable for very low power battery-based operation?  Specifically, in an application where a device wakes up periodically (e.g. for data collection) or activated by a user button press?

Comment: Related to your previous question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55813/converting-a-standard-setup-loop-sketch-to-a-low-power-application

Answer (score 4):

Technically you can use any arduino for that purpose with some modifications. I recommend to go with an arduino Pro Mini and remove the LED and the voltage regulator. [image]
But if you don't need so much I/O you can go with a digispark Attiny board.
[image]

Comment: To program a pro-mini you need a separate usb-to-serial adapter for programming (or a spare Arduino UNO)